# angular 4 animations - transition duration is not applied

Tags: animation, typescript, web-deployment, angular

what am I doing wrong? The transition happens but it's instant. The time set in animate function is not being applied

```
trigger('showMenu', [
  state('active', style({
    marginLeft: '0px'
  })),
  state('inactive', style({
    marginLeft: '-230px'
  })),
  transition('inactive => active', animate('2s')),
  transition('active => inactive', animate('2s'))
])

<div [@showMenu]="showMenuState" id="menu-side-wrapper">
    MENU
    <div id="close-menu">
       CLOSE
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked the code you've pasted here and it works fine. Could you add any other relevant code? Maybe the code for 'showMenuState'?

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I created a new project and ported the code there. I guess it was caused by some html markup/css, because all .ts files stayed the same

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the exact problem in my project by **removing** the import of **NoopAnimationsModule** in my main module. This one seems to mock the animations, but actually doesn't do a thing.