# Update angular 2.3 => 4.1.3 animations broken

Tags: angular, angular-animations

i Hi everyone,
i have a little problem with my animations  :

```
animations: [
    trigger('toggle', [
        state('shown', style({transform: 'translate3d(0,0,0)'})),
        transition('hidden => *', [
            animate('300ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.130, 0.5, 0.950)', style({transform: 'translate3d(0,0,0)'}))
        ]),
        transition('* => shown', [
            animate('300ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.130, 0.5, 0.950)', style({transform: 'translate3d(0,0,0)'}))
        ]),
        transition('shown => hidden', [
            animate('300ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.130, 0.5, 0.950)', style({transform: 'translate3d(100%,0,0)'}))
        ]),
    ])
]
```

call like this :

```
<div class="cars-popin-wrap" [@toggle]="stateToggle" > 
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

it works in angular2 but not in angular 4.
I changed the animations from 'core' to 'animations' but nothing changed.

Anyone know how i can solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you import the npm package?
npm install @angular/animations@latest --save
Module.ts : 
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

Comment: Yes my package is imported (in version 4.1.3), the '@latest' install the 5.2.0 which don't work with angular 4.1.3, and the import is done too. Is it possible the version of my animation is the problem ?(i tried with angular 4.4 and the problem was the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bob's answer on [Angular 4 animations - transition duration is not applied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48951291):

You can solve it by removing `NoopAnimationsModule` from my `app.module.ts`

Comment: It works great, thanks. But "NoopAnimationsModule" allow to name trigger state with 'true' 'false' values (agreed it's not the best ^^), so if you have 'true' 'false' in state, the animation won't work (I had this bug in another animation and had to rename my states).  Thanks a lot dude